# microsoft azure - resource group vs container group

Tags: azure

what is the difference between "resource group" and "container group" in ms azure?
I tried ms docs but could not find a clear distinction, seems like resource group is a single container while container group is a collection of containers but I am not sure if I got it right.
thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top-level resource in **Azure Container Instances** is the **container group**. It's a collection of containers (Docker containers) that get scheduled on the same host machine. The containers in a container group share a lifecycle, resources, local network, and storage volumes. It's similar in concept to a pod in Kubernetes.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-container-groups

A **resource group** is a logical folder (not a Docker container), that groups resources (other Azure services) for an Azure solution.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/manage-resource-groups-portal

Comment: but in relation to each other what can contain what? a resource group contains container group or resource group is contained only inside a single container?

Comment: A container is contained in a container group that is contained in an Azure Container Instance that is contained in a resource group that is contained in an Azure subscription

Answer (score 0):

Resource group

A resource group is a container that holds related resources for an Azure solution.
The resource group can include all the resources for the solution, or only those resources that you want to manage as a group.
You decide how you want to allocate resources to resource groups based on what makes the most sense for your organization.
Generally, add resources that share the same lifecycle to the same resource group so you can easily deploy, update, and delete them as a group.
The resource group stores metadata about the resources. Therefore, when you specify a location for the resource group, you are specifying where that metadata is stored.
For compliance reasons, you may need to ensure that your data is stored in a particular region.

Resource: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/manage-resource-groups-portal

Container group

A set of containers that all run on the same host computer is known to be as a container group in Microsoft azure.
A container group's lifespan, resources, local network, and storage volumes are all shared by the containers in the group.
It's similar to a Kubernetes pod in terms of idea.
A Microsoft's Azure resource's network configuration template is a network profile.
This network profile is the one which provides the resource's network attributes, such as the subnet into which it should be deployed.
If we are going to deploy the container group into a subnet and then to a virtual network, then the azure produces a network profile for us when we use the az container create command.

Resource: https://www.javatpoint.com/what-is-a-container-group-in-microsoft-azure